# Error: Property [tit] does not exist on this collection instance - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show my records on my category page. But I'm faced with a problem. I'm sorry for my bad English.

> error: Property [movies] does not exist on this collection instance.

**KategoriController.php (controller):**

```
 public function index()
 {
    $kategori =Kategori::All();
    $filmler = $kategori->filmler;

    return view('kategori', compact( 'kategori', 'filmler'));
}
```

**Film.php (Model):**

```
public function kategoriler()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Kategori', 'kategori_film');
}
```

**Kategori.php (Model):**

```
public function filmler()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Film', 'kategori_film');
}
```

*can you please help?*

Comment: `all()` returns a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections) so it will not have property `filmler`, you might need `Kategori::first()->filmler` to get the first result only or use more filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `with` in your controller instead of the first two lines

```
 public function index()
{

    $kategori = Kategori::with('filmler')->get();

    return view('kategori', compact( 'kategori'));
}
```